# How to preserve the client IP towards the GCP kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have this K8s deployment that creates a simple NGINX server and serves/replay some information related to the request. There is no upstream. I want to get the real client IP of the incoming requests that are coming through the internet.
I printed the X-Forwarded-For header, but it's empty.
I am using the GCP Kubernetes service.

I tried this but there is no luck.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip

````
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-config
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          subPath: nginx.conf
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-config
        configMap:
          name: nginx-config
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    events {}
    http {
      server {
        listen 80;
        location /info {
          default_type 'application/json';
          add_header 'X-Forwarded-For' '$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for';
          return 200 '{ "remote_port": "$remote_port", "remote_addr": "$remote_addr", "server_time": "$msec", "client_timestamp": "$http_x_client_timestamp","tcpinfo_rtt": "$tcpinfo_rtt", "tcpinfo_rttvar": "$tcpinfo_rttvar", "tcpinfo_snd_cwnd": "$tcpinfo_snd_cwnd", "tcpinfo_rcv_space": "$tcpinfo_rcv_space" }';
        }
        location /headers {
          default_type 'application/json';
          add_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
          return 200 '{ "headers": $http_x_forwarded_for }';
        }
      }
    }


```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to [set `externalTrafficPolicy` to local](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/service-parameters#externalTrafficPolicy) in your Service spec:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: its not working the $http_x_forwarded_for header is empty. Am I accessing the wrong thing?